# Why aren't my players teleported to spawn? (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: location.world)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

**EDIT 01/04/20:** Solved the issue by myself.

After implementing file writing/reading according to this tutorial, it works fine now:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3en6w7PNL08

I think the following line (created in the first implementation), caused the error:

```
==: org.bukkit.Location
```

It's no longer included in newly written files.

---

**Original Text:**

I'm trying to develop a minigame plugin like survival games just for fun. If two players have joined the lobby, a countdown starts. After the countdown has expired, they will be teleported to their player spawns.

From the `Countdown` class I try to call the `LocationManager` class, to retrieve the spawns stored in the config.yml (content below).

```
// Class 'Countdown' inner countdown method
Template.main.lm.mapTeleport();
```

---

```
// Class 'LocationManager' - method 'mapTeleport'

/**
 * Teleports player to player spawn
 */
public void mapTeleport() {
    int count = 1;
    for(Player alive : Template.main.alive) {
        alive.teleport(getSpawn(count));
        count++;
    }
}
```

These `mapTeleport` method calls the `getSpawn` method, the most central method in this case.

```
public File file = new File("plugins/"+ Template.main.getName() + "/Locations","locs.yml");
public FileConfiguration cfg = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);

/**
 * Gets an existing spawn location
 * @param num The spawn ID
 * @return The location
 */
public Location getSpawn(int num) {
    String name = "Spawn";

    // Get requested world
    World world = Bukkit.getWorld(cfg.getString(name + "." + num + ".world"));
    double x = cfg.getDouble(name + "." + num + ".x");
    double y = cfg.getDouble(name + "." + num + ".y");
    double z = cfg.getDouble(name + "." + num + ".z");

    // Create location from world data
    Location loc = new Location(world, x, y, z);
    loc.setPitch(cfg.getInt(name + "." + num + ".yaw"));
    loc.setPitch(cfg.getInt(name + "." + num + ".pitch"));

    return loc;
}
```

---

I think this line causing the problem, or rather the configuration access:

```
World world = Bukkit.getWorld(cfg.getString(name + "." + num + ".world"));
```

This is the error I get each time the countdown expires:

```
[19:06:12 WARN]: Task #5 for CMDPlugin v1.0.0 generated an exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: location.world
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:122) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-143]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.entity.CraftPlayer.teleport(CraftPlayer.java:742) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-143]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.entity.CraftEntity.teleport(CraftEntity.java:491) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-143]
    at de.foobar.net.manager.LocationManager.mapTeleport(LocationManager.java:108) ~[?:?]
    at de.foobar.net.countdowns.Countdown$1.run(Countdown.java:48) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:84) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-143]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:452) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-143]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:1185) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-143]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:430) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-143]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1112) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-143]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:934) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-143]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
```

---

And this is my config.yml:

```
lobby:
  world: world
  x: -197.4875119294138
  y: 69.0
  z: -124.49595934260542
  yaw: -1.0501342
  pitch: 8.850019
Spawn:
  '1':
    world:
      ==: org.bukkit.Location
      world: world
      x: -194.4864683733013
      y: 69.0
      z: -121.545448660259
      pitch: 7.649753
      yaw: -247.349
    x: -194.4864683733013
    y: 69.0
    z: -121.545448660259
    yaw: -247.349
    pitch: 7.649753
  '2':
    world:
      ==: org.bukkit.Location
      world: world
      x: -199.4815091840693
      y: 69.0
      z: -121.45661018875579
      pitch: 2.9999316
      yaw: -134.54874
    x: -199.4815091840693
    y: 69.0
    z: -121.45661018875579
    yaw: -134.54874
    pitch: 2.9999316
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you get this line from and what is it supposed to do? `==: org.bukkit.Location`

Comment: It was added automatically and I don't know what it was supposed to do. Guess this was used in an earlier version of the game.